# How can I start auto-completion for algorithm package in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

[image: TeXstudio settings]

As shown in image, I have checked `algorithm.cwl`, and I am sure I have `\usepackage{algorithm}` in my source, but the command related to this package cannot auto-completed. Who can tell me why, thank you.

Comment: Strangely enough, even though I have the same checkboxes you do, there is no corresponding cwl-file for algorithm in my texstudio-folder. If this is the same for you, you can always create your own .cwl file.

Comment: See here for background information: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion

Comment: how to create cwl file

Comment: See [the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION), or just look in one of the other `.cwl` files.